# Как выбрать все вхождения в регулярном выражении PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

> 1. Иванов Иван Иванович - оказываются услуги проживания (2-х местный двухкомнатный Люкс, Основное место), услуги питания (Заказное меню), медицинские услуги (Лечение), услуги, связанные с организацией туристического путешествия; 2. Петров Пётр Петрович - оказываются услуги проживания (2-х местный двухкомнатный Люкс, Дополнительное место), услуги питания (Заказное меню), услуги, связанные с организацией туристического путешествия (без оказания медицинских услуг); 3. Семенов Семён Семёнович - оказываются медицинские услуги (Лечение), услуги, связанные с организацией туристического путешествия (без оказания услуг проживания, услуг питания);

Нужно при помощи регулярного выражения на php убрать текст между ", услуги," и ";". То есть нужно получить строку вида:

> 1. Иванов Иван Иванович - оказываются услуги проживания (2-х местный двухкомнатный Люкс, Основное место), услуги питания (Заказное меню), медицинские услуги (Лечение) 2. Петров Пётр Петрович - оказываются услуги проживания (2-х местный двухкомнатный Люкс, Дополнительное место), услуги питания (Заказное меню) 3. Семенов Семён Семёнович - оказываются медицинские услуги (Лечение)

Пишу вот эту регулярку, и выбирается только одно вхождение.

```
/, услуги,[^)]+;/
```

Как сделать, чтобы выбирались все случаи в строке?
Для удобства - ссылка на https://regex101.com/r/VYmAld/1

Comment: `preg_replace` пробовали? Регулярка ваша - [рабочая](https://regex101.com/r/U5JEXM/1) (я заменил `)` на `;`, но и без этого работало. Только на том сайте нужно флаг `g` использовать, а в PHP достаточно `preg_replace`). Regex101 вам даже [код сам пишет](https://regex101.com/r/U5JEXM/2/codegen?language=php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал так:

```
/, услуги,[^;]+;/
```

и включил флаг global на том сайте.

В PHP будет:

```
$str = '1. Иванов Иван Иванович - оказываются услуги проживания (2-х местный двухкомнатный Люкс, Основное место), услуги питания (Заказное меню), медицинские услуги (Лечение), услуги, связанные с организацией туристического путешествия; 2. Петров Пётр Петрович - оказываются услуги проживания (2-х местный двухкомнатный Люкс, Дополнительное место), услуги питания (Заказное меню), услуги, связанные с организацией туристического путешествия (без оказания медицинских услуг); 3. Семенов Семён Семёнович - оказываются медицинские услуги (Лечение), услуги, связанные с организацией туристического путешествия (без оказания услуг проживания, услуг питания);';

$result = preg_replace('/, услуги,[^;]+;/', '', $str);
```